# insert text after specified string using php

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I want to add text to a file after specified string using PHP.

For example, I want to add the word 'ldaps' after `#redundant LDAP {` string

I used this code without result:

```
$lines = array();
foreach(file("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default") as $line) {
    if ("redundant LDAP {" === $line) {
        array_push($lines, 'ldaps');
    }
    array_push($lines, $line);
}
file_put_contents("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default", $lines);
```

The only thing this code does is put lines into an array and then insert to the file without adding the word.

Comment: Where does `$server` come from?

Comment: You dont even **attempt** to add the word `ldaps` to anything in this code

Comment: Whats the content of the file `default`?

Comment: contain text but I want to append word 'ldaps' after line which contain 'redundant LDAP {'

Comment: Can you include an example text and what you want it to look like? I think there is a much easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lines = array();

foreach(file("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default") as $line)) {
    // first switch these lines so you write the line and then add the new line after it

    array_push($lines, $line);

    // then test if the line contains so you dont miss a line
    // because there is a newline of something at the end of it
    if (strpos($line, "redundant LDAP {") !== FALSE) {
        array_push($lines, 'ldaps');
    }
}
file_put_contents("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default", $lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you only should modify your `file_put_contents` code and it should work. `file_put_contents` expect and string, but you want to pass an array. Using `join`, you could combine the array to an string again.

In addition to that, you might also want to add trim to your compare, to avoid problems with spaces and tabs.

```
$lines = array();
foreach(file("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default") as $line) {
    // should be before the comparison, for the correct order
    $lines[] = $line;
    if ("redundant LDAP {" === trim($line)) {
        $lines[] = 'ldaps';
    }
}
$content = join("\n", $lines);
file_put_contents("/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default", $content);
```